# Find string not preceded by other string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to get only `['bar']` here:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?<!\bdef )([a-zA-Z0-9.]+?)\(", "def foo(): bar()")
['oo', 'bar']
```

Is that possible in a single regex? If not, i'll use this first: `re.sub(r"\bdef [a-zA-Z0-9.]+", "", "def foo(): bar()")`

Comment: Use [`\b(?<!\bdef )([a-zA-Z_][\w.]*)\(`](https://regex101.com/r/pgW4RC/2). A word boundary will make matching inside a word impossible.

Comment: Add a `\b` after the lookbehind.

Comment: @Aran-Fey It is better if `\b` is placed before the lookbehind so that it is executed only after word boundary positions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current regex matches `oo` in `foo` because `oo(` is not preceded with `"def "`.

To stop the pattern from matching inside a word, you may use a a word boundary, `\b` and the fix might look like [`r"\b(?<!\bdef )([a-zA-Z0-9.]+?)\("`](https://regex101.com/r/Tu4qjJ/1).

Note that identifiers can be matched with `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so your pattern can be enhanced like

```
re.findall(r'\b(?<!\bdef\s)([a-zA-Z_]\w*(?:\.[a-zA-Z_]\w*)*)\(', s, re.A)
```

Note that [`re.A` or `re.ASCII`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.A) will make `\w` match ASCII only letters, digits and `_`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rMkcXs/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\bdef\s)` - no `def` + space allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `([a-zA-Z_]\w*(?:\.[a-zA-Z_]\w*)*)` - Capturing group 1 (its value will be the result of `re.findall` call):

  - `[a-zA-Z_]` - an ASCII letter or `_`
  - `\w*` - 1+ word chars
  - `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group matching a sequence of...

    - `\.` - a dot
    - `[a-zA-Z_]` - an ASCII letter or `_`
    - `\w*` - 1+ word chars
- `)*` - ... zero or more times
- `\(` - a `(` char.